# Create a new hash from an existing array of hashes

Tags: ruby

I am newbie to ruby . I have an array of hashes `input_array`

```
[{
"name"=>"test1", 
"zone_status"=>"valid", 
"certificate_status"=>"valid", 
"users"=>1000,
"name"=>"test2", 
"zone_status"=>"valid", 
"certificate_status"=>"valid", 
"users"=>5000,
"name"=>"test3", 
"zone_status"=>"valid", 
"certificate_status"=>"valid", 
"users"=>3000,
"name"=>"test4", 
"zone_status"=>"valid", 
"certificate_status"=>"valid", 
"users"=>2000}]
```

and an array

```
existing_names_array  = ["test1","test2"]
```

The below line gets me all the names into `input_names`

```
input_array.each_with_index {|val, index| input_names << input_array[index]['name'] }
```

But how can I get the `input_names` to be a hash with `name` as key and its respective `users` as value?
Because my final goal is to check the names  which are in input_names, but not in  `existing_names_array` and get a count of those names and users

As the names `tes1,test2` exists in `existing_names_array`, I need the count of rest of `names` and count of their respective `users` in `input_array`

Expected output:

```
output_names = test3, test 4
total_output_names = 2

output_users = 3000,2000
total_output_users = 5000
```

Comment: `input_array` executed by itself returns `=> [{"name"=>"test4", "zone_status"=>"valid", "certificate_status"=>"valid", "users"=>2000}]`. That's because it is an array containing one element, a hash, and because that hash has keys that appear more than once (`'name'`, `'zone_status'`, ...) they are overwritten. That's why `input_array['name'] #=> 'test4'`, `test4'` being the value of the last instance of the key `'name'` in the hash. Perhaps you meant that `input_array` is an array of four hashes: `[{'name'=>'name1,..,'users'=>1000}, {'name'='name2',...}...]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use ActiveSupport's [Enumerable#index_by](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Enumerable.html#method-i-index_by) with Ruby core's [Hash#transform_values](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Hash.html#method-i-transform_values) it's pretty easy, if I'm understanding your question correctly:

```
# add gem 'activesupport' to Gemfile, or use Rails, then ..
require 'active_support/all'

users_and_counts = input_array.
  index_by { |hsh| hsh["name"] }.
  transform_values { |hsh| hsh["users"] }

# => { "test1" => 1000, "test2" => 5000, ... }
```

You can do this with [Enumerable#reduce](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-reduce) (or [Enumerable#each_with_object](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_object)) as well:

```
users_and_counts = input_array.reduce({}) do |memo, hsh|
  memo[hsh["name"]] = hsh["users"]
  memo
end
```

Or, the simplest way, with good old `each`:

```
users_and_counts = {}
input_array.each do |hsh|
  users_and_counts[hsh["name"]] = hsh["users"]
end
```

---

**in response to comment**

In general, there are a few ways to check whether an element is found in an array:

```
array = ["foo", "bar"]

# 1. The simple standard way
array.include?("foo") # => true

# 2. More efficient way
require 'set'
set = Set.new(array)
set.member?("foo") # => true
```

So with this knowledge we can break up our task into a few steps:

1. Make a new hash which is a copy of the one we built above, but without the key-vals corresponding to users in the `existing_names_array` (see [Hash#select](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Hash.html#method-i-select) and [Hash#reject](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Hash.html#method-i-reject)):

   ```
    require 'set'
    existing_names_set = Set.new(existing_names_array)
    new_users_and_counts = users_and_counts.reject do |name, count|
      existing_names_set.member?(name)
    end
    # => { "test3" => 3000, "test4" => 2000 }
   ```
2. Use [Hash#keys](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Hash.html#method-i-keys) to get the list of user names:

   ```
    new_user_names = new_users_and_counts.keys
    # => ["test3", "test4"]
   ```
3. Use [Hash#values](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Hash.html#method-i-values) to get the list of counts:

   ```
   new_user_counts = new_users_and_counts.values
   # => [3000, 2000]
   ```

Comment: Thank you max. Once I get the `result` hash, how can I check if the keys of this hash are in array `existing_names_array` and if a match is not found is it advisable to make a non-match hash for `name` and `users` to get a total of them?

Comment: Updated answer @Jill448

Answer (score 2):

I assume `input_array` is to be as follows.

```
input_array = [
  { "name"=>"test1", "zone_status"=>"valid", "certificate_status"=>"valid",
    "users"=>1000 },
  { "name"=>"test2", "zone_status"=>"valid", "certificate_status"=>"valid",
    "users"=>5000 },
  { "name"=>"test3", "zone_status"=>"valid", "certificate_status"=>"valid",
    "users"=>3000 },
  { "name"=>"test4", "zone_status"=>"valid", "certificate_status"=>"valid",
    "users"=>2000}
]
```

We are also given:

```
names = ["test1", "test2"]
```

The information of interest can be represented nicely by the following hash (which I will construct):

```
summary = { "test1"=>1000, "test2"=>5000 }
```

We might use that to compute the following.

```
names = summary.keys
  #=> ["test1", "test2"] 
users = summary.values
  #=> [1000, 5000] 
total_users = users.sum
  #=> 6000
```

There are many ways to construct the hash `summary`. I prefer the following.

```
summary = input_array.each_with_object({}) do |g,h|
  key = g["name"]
  h[key] = g["users"] if names.include?(key)
end
  #=> {"test1"=>1000, "test2"=>5000}
```

---

Another way is as follows.

```
summary = input_array.map { |g| g.values_at("name", "users") }.
  .to_h
  .slice(*names)
```

See [Hash#values_at(https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Hash.html#method-i-values_at), [Array#to_h](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Array.html#method-i-to_h) and [Hash#slice](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Hash.html#method-i-slice). The steps are as follows.

```
arr = input_array.map { |g| g.values_at("name", "users") }
  #=> [["test1", 1000], ["test2", 5000], ["test3", 3000], ["test4", 2000]] 
h = arr.to_h
  #=> {"test1"=>1000, "test2"=>5000, "test3"=>3000, "test4"=>2000} 
summary = h.slice(*names)
  #=> {"test1"=>1000, "test2"=>5000}
```

The *splat* operator converts `h.slice(*names)`, which is `h.slice(*["test1", "test2"])`, to `h.slice("test1", "test2")`. That's because `Hash#slice` was defined to accept a variable number of keys as arguments, rather than an array of keys as the argument.